# Deleting Rows in UITableView Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

okay im making an app where you add items to a cart and it updates as you add. i do all the adding fine, but i cant get deleting to work. in the cart cell i would need to remove from 3 arrays, but that doesn't seem to be the problem because i keep getting this error:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'"

i'm not really sure what i'm doing wrong here. i've followed a few tutorials and they all seem to be doing the same thing. any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

heres some of my code:

```
//declaring arrays to show in cell
var cartKeys = [String]()
var cartValues = [String]()

var deets = [[String]]()
var count = 0


//populating arrays from original arrays 
func populateCart(){

    for (key,value) in MenuStore.shared.cart {

        self.cartKeys.append(key)
        self.cartValues.append(value)
    }


    for i in MenuStore.shared.cartAndItems{
        for (k,v) in i {
            deets.append(v)
        }
    }

    print("DEETS \(deets)")

    for c in cartView.visibleCells {

        count += 1

    }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch tableView{

    case cartView:
        if editingStyle == .delete{
            let index = indexPath.row
            print(index)

            cartKeys.remove(at: index)
            cartValues.remove(at: index)

            deets.remove(at: index)


            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

        }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch tableView{

    case cartView:
        let cartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath) as? CartCell


        cartCell?.cartTitle.text = cartKeys[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cartCell?.cartPrice.text = cartValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cartCell?.cartDetails.text = deets[count].joined(separator: ", ")



        return cartCell!
```

ps. if anyone wants to help with replacing the visible cells call thatd be great. id like to loop through all the cells even if their not visible on the screen.

Comment: You need to really first learn how `cellForRowAt IndexPath` works because you are adding object inside the `cellForRowAt IndexPath` that is so much wrong.

Comment: how else do you do it? i havent seen any other way.

Comment: The for loop iteration must be some where else and then reload the tableView after array object is added.

Comment: okay. once i do that should everything work?

Comment: Also you need to change the logic of count one,

Comment: how so? i dont mean to sound rude, but could please be more descriptive?

Comment: Can you the screen shot of what you want and the structure of your array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123972/discussion-between-user3462448-and-nirav-d).

Comment: appending data in cellforrow... is bad prog. practice.

Comment: i want to delete a row in my tableview. when i do that i have the three arrays you see in the question. i just dont know how to delete from their index. 
var cart = [(String,String)]() 
var cartAndItems = [[String:[String]]]()
those are the arrays im looping through
to populate cartKeys, cartValue, and deets

Comment: i fixed it Mr. UB :)

Comment: Please share your fix in your original question.

Comment: i did probably 10 seconds before you posted the comment. hah